# Traefik multiple duplicate port/overlapping ports

Tags: docker, traefik

Trying to set up my docker-compose for all my services, and I run a few sonarr/radarr and custom apache containers.

I understand that I could change radarr/sonarr to use a different port than 8989/7979 and use that port in traefik, but id run into the same problems with multiple port 80's for my apache containers.

So my questions, in my caddyfile I could normally forward my port 80 to 6969 for example, then 6969 to radarr4k.hostname. How would I do that in my traefik docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

- create an entrypoint (`foo`) on port 6969
- set these entrypoint on the container (with the label `traefik.frontend.entryPoints=foo`)
- add a frontend rule on the container (with the label `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:radarr4k.hostname`

More information:

- https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/
- https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/